# Xamarin.iOS equivalent to Xamarin.Android's CookieManager.Instance

Tags: ios, xamarin, cookies, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working with Cookies in my Xamarin Forms App.

At some point, I need to get the stored Cookies as a string.

In Android, I can resolve this as `CookieManager.Instance.GetCookie(url);` which returns a string of all Cookies, seperated with a ;

I am looking for an equivalent for Xamarin.iOS, since I am developing a cross-platform application.

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41039/setting-cookies-in-a-webview I think this answer can help you.

Comment: @Jaymin already looked at that. Maybe it is me, but I could not find this part. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @ Robert Haslinger Did you solve it ？

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Not yet. Since Ihave access to each cookie's info, I will just implement that feature by myself. I can post my solution as answer when I am finished if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS does not provide such a method, I have implemented it myself. For anyone interested, here is my code:

```
public string GetCookieString(string url)
    {
        NSHttpCookie[] cookieArray = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.CookiesForUrl(new NSUrl(Constants.PROXY_URL));
        string cookieString = "";

        NSHttpCookie lastCookie = cookieArray.Last();
        foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in cookieArray)
        {
            cookieString = cookieString + cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value;
            if (!(cookie==lastCookie))
            {
                cookieString = cookieString + "; ";
            }
        }
        return cookieString;
    }
```

I could not test it yet, but it should provide me with a string which looks this:

```
cookieString= "name=value; name=value; name=value"
```

Comment: @r15 I know that I cannot expect to get an 100% accurate answer, but this is an issue that others will encounter too eventually. So I think publishing my own workaround is not wrong. I am not that familiar with what is correct and what is not on Stack Overflow. Thanks for your feedback, but I think that i did nothing wrong in that case.

Comment: Hello @Robert, where did you put it? I've tried putting it in WebviewRenderer, DecidePolicy but didn't work.

Comment: Hey @Erdogan can you post a question on Stack Overflow and put more details into it? It is easier to help you that way.

Answer (score 4):

In iOS if you are using NSUrlSession, your cookies are shared automatically with the UIWebView/WKWebView and NSUrlSession.

To access the Cookie Container, you just need to call upon by using **DependencyService** or **Custom Renderer** .

```
NSHttpCookieStorage shareStore = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
var cookies = shareStore.CookiesForUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

For iOS you need to use `NSHttpCookieStorage`  class. You need to create `Dependecny Service` class in your iOS project.

```
NSHttpCookieStorage CookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
var cookie = CookieStorage.CookiesForUrl(url);
```

For more information how to implement it, you can visit [this url](https://blog.wislon.io/posts/2016/01/24/xamforms-quick-and-dirty-cookies-access).

Comment: I know, but I was looking for a cheap solution for my specific problem. I really need to get the exact same string as in Android. Maybe I just have to implement it by myself then.

Comment: Are you using dependency service? If yes then pass URL param, you will get same string as in Android. If you need help for dependency service let me know.

Comment: I am, yes. Which method will return that string?

Comment: If you see 2nd line of my code `cookie` will have resultant value provided if you are passing URL

Comment: Well, cookie will just have properties like Name,Value,... . So as I said, I will take them and add their values to my string.

Comment: Yes. Those values you need to pick up from `cookie`. You can see example in url, above I have given.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I totally forgot about that link. Thanks.